# Symfony 3.3 EntityType using distinct values in a drop down

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am working on an existing Symfony 3.3 project, and I have been asked to register a dropdown field in a results filter form that should contain all the values from a field in the database.

Until now, what I have do is the following that partially works:

```
$builder->add(
    'newField',
    EntityType::class,
    [
        'class'        => Transaction::class,
        'required'     => false,
        'multiple'     => false,
        'label'        => 'New Field',
        'choice_label' => 'newField',
        'placeholder'  => 'Choose a value'
    ]
)
```

The above code is able to display the values correctly, but unfortunately, because the table has repeatedly the same values, I get a long list of all the same values.

Instead, what I need to achieve is to display the `DISTINCT` values from the database.

I have tried the query_builder, but to be honest I am not sure I use it correctly as I am not an experienced Symfony developer.

Any idea on how to display the entries of the given column with `DISTINCT` results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said yourself, you can use the query builder to achieve this. Something as simple as this should achieve what you're after:

```
->add('fooBar', EntityType::class, [
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
        return $repository
            ->createQueryBuilder('f')
            ->distinct();
    },
]);
```

You can also specify a flag to be distinct and remember not to return the result but return the query. You can read more [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder)

Comment: Hello @Mylesk. Thank you for your reply and your time :). Unfortunately, that doesn't work :( . I get the error message `Undefined method 'distinct'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!`

Comment: @MerianosNikos I've updated the query builder, I was missing `createQueryBuilder`, that may be the reason why

Comment: this is how it finally worked out: `return $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')->select('t')->groupBy('t.siteDomain');`

Answer (score 2):

You are right,

Query_builder is the way to go.

So first create the method of what you want to do in **TransactionRepository**.

```
class TransactionRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    //....
    public function getDistinctValues()
    {
        //Return what you want to get, I cannot write this for you without your entity
    }
}
```

Then use it in the **FormType** :

```
$builder->add(
    'newField',
    EntityType::class,
    [
        'class'        => Transaction::class,
        'required'     => false,
        'multiple'     => false,
        'label'        => 'New Field',
        'choice_label' => 'newField',
        'placeholder'  => 'Choose a value',
        'query_builder' => function(TransactionRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->getDistinctValues();
                }
    ]
)
```

And you should be good to go.